# Changing color when rendering SVG in PDFBox

Tags: java, svg, pdfbox, graphics2d

Does anybody know how to change color when rendering SVG into PDF with *pdfbox* ?

I am using following code:

```java
File svgFile = new File("roots.svg");

SVGUniverse svgUniverse = new SVGUniverse();
SVGDiagram diagram = svgUniverse.getDiagram(svgUniverse.loadSVG(svgFile.toURL()));

PdfBoxGraphics2D graphics = new PdfBoxGraphics2D(document, 32, 32);
graphics.setColor(Color.green);

try {
    diagram.render(graphics);
} catch (SVGException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} finally {
    graphics.dispose();
}

PDFormXObject xform = graphics.getXFormObject();

try (PDPageContentStream contentWriter = new PDPageContentStream(document, page, PDPageContentStream.AppendMode.APPEND, false)) {
    AffineTransform transform = AffineTransform.getTranslateInstance(0, 0);
    transform.scale(2,2);
    xform.setMatrix(transform);
    contentWriter.setNonStrokingColor(Color.green);
    contentWriter.setStrokingColor(Color.green);
    contentWriter.drawForm(xform);
}
```

With following dependencies:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.pdfbox</groupId>
    <artifactId>pdfbox</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.25</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.weblookandfeel</groupId>
    <artifactId>svg-salamander</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.2.2</version>
</dependency>
```

But the Icon appears black instead of green.

Thanks in advance to everybody!

```java
contentWriter.setNonStrokingColor(Color.green);
contentWriter.setStrokingColor(Color.green);
```

Changes nothing.

Comment: don't forget to update pdfbox to 2.0.29.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
diagram.getRoot().addAttribute("fill", AnimationElement.AT_CSS, colorLight);+
```

Comment: This works really great. Thank you.